# Dividing an array into two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, sub-array

I have an array (rows) with **n** nodes. Each node contains 6 elements.

**Example:**

```
rows[0]: ["1", "Text", "0", "55", "0", "Text 2"]
rows[1]: ["2", "Another Text", "15.5", "55", "16.6", "Another Text 2"]
...
rows[n]: [...]
```

I want to put the second element (like `["Text", "Another Text", ...])` from all of rows [n] into the separate array

**and**

I want to put the third and the fifth elements(like `[[0, 0], [15.5, 16.6], ...]`) into the separate array too.
I think I need `foreach` in the `foreach`.

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Lots of ways to do this using a variety of different loop approaches

Comment: `rows.map((arr) => arr[n])`?

Comment: Try. Always try first - and then show us what was your approach. You'll learn more by doing that than by copy/pasting some of the answers that someone is inevitably going to give you. https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the multiple approaches (It uses `Array#forEach`),

```
let arrays = [
 ["1", "Text", "0", "55", "0", "Text 2"],
 ["2", "Another Text", "15.5", "55", "16.6", "Another Text 2"]
];

let withIndex1 = [];
let withIndex2And4 = [];

arrays.forEach((arr) => {
  withIndex1.push(arr[1]);
  withIndex2And4.push([arr[2],arr[4]]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with simple `Array#map`:

```js
const rows = [
   ["1", "Text", "0", "55", "0", "Text 2"],
   ["2", "Another Text", "15.5", "55", "16.6", "Another Text 2"],
];

const r = (d, n) => rows.map((arr) => arr[n]);

console.log(r(rows, 1));
console.log(r(rows, 2));
```

Comment: looks great, but `console.log(r(rows, 1));
console.log(r(rows, 2, 4));` doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Not so beautiful, but I think more readable:

```
let row = [
    ["1", "Text", "0", "55", "0", "Text 2"],
    ["2", "Second Text", "15.5", "55", "16.6", "Second Text 2"],
    ["3", "Third Text", "17", "60", "18", "Third Text 2"]
];

let arrA = [], arrB = [];

function newArrA(el, arr) {
    arr.forEach(arrEl => arrA.push(arrEl[el-1]));
}

function newArrB(elA, elB, arr) {

    arr.forEach(arrEl => arrB.push( [ arrEl[elA-1], arrEl[elB-1] ] ) );

}

newArrA(2, row);
// arrA: ["Text", "Second Text", "Third Text"]

newArrB(3, 5, row);
// arrB[0]: ["0", "0"]
// arrB[1]: ["15.5", "16.6"]
// arrB[2]: ["17", "18"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could transpose the matrix and take the wanted columns and transpose again for getting the wanted result.

```js
const
    transpose = (r, a) => a.map((v, i) => [...(r[i] || []), v]),
    array = [["1", "Text", "0", "55", "0", "Text 2"], ["2", "Another Text", "15.5", "55", "16.6", "Another Text 2"]],
    columns = array.reduce(transpose, []),
    ad1 = columns[1],
    ad2 = [columns[2], columns[4]].reduce(transpose, []);

console.log(ad1);
console.log(ad2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```